# Redirect changes hostname

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, redirect, iis

From my app, I am sending a redirect to the browser, but what I see in the Response header Location is the same hostname and results in an error since that controller doesn't exist in my app. The hostnames are very similar, but are slightly different. What could be happening to make IIS change the hostname on the redirect location?

From the details below, the hostname is changing from "*blah.home.mysite.com*" to "*home.mysite.com*" and the request/302 response is on the "*home.mysite.com*" hostname.

Here are the details:
My app in admin: http://home.mysite.com/admin/doSomething
Site to Redirect: http://blah.home.mysite.com/someUrl/more
Location sent to browser: http://home.mysite.com/somUrl/more
Status code sent to browser: 302

When I manually paste the "Site to Redirect" into the browser, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the reverse proxy - in case someone else has the same issue. The "Reverse rewrite host in response headers" option needed to be checked.

See this post for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23600821/156611